# Subscribe to an event many times with EventHandlerList

Tags: c#, events, synchronization

The goal: I want to subscribe many times to the same event in different classes. I have the following class:

```
public class MyEngine : IEngine
{
    private EventHandlerList _events = new EventHandlerList();

    protected EventHandlerList Events
    {
        get
        {
            return _events;
        }
    }

    private readonly string OnReceivedEventName = "OnReceived";

    public event MessageEventHandler OnReceived
    {
        add
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Events.AddHandler(OnReceivedEventName, value);
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Events.RemoveHandler(OnReceivedEventName, value);
            }
        }
    }

    protected internal virtual void MessageReceived(MessageEventArgs e)
    {

        var handler = Events[OnReceivedEventName] as MessageEventHandler;
        TryFireMessageEvent(handler, e);
    }

    private void TryFireMessageEvent(MessageEventHandler handler, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (handler != null)
                handler.Invoke(this, e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Message Received - Exception caught", ex);
            ErrorOccurred(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The main module has an instance of IEngine:

```
public class MyProvider
{
    protected internal IEngine Engine { get; set; }
    public MyProvider(IEngine engine)
    {
        Engine = engine;
        engine.OnReceived += Engine_Received;
    }
    protected internal void Engine_Received(IEngine engine, MessageEventArgs args)
    {...}
}
```

I also have a function 'DoAction' that create an operation and inject the engine:

```
public class MyProvider
{
    ....
    public Result DoAction()
    {
        using (var operation = new SyncOperation(Engine))
        {
            operationResult = operation.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

The SyncOperation:

```
public class SyncOperation : IDisposable
{
    private IEngine _engine;

    public SyncOperation (IEngine engine)
    {
        Ensure.NotNull(engine, "engine");
        _engine = engine;

        _engine.OnReceived += Engine_OnReceived;
    }

    internal void Engine_OnReceived(IEngine engine, MessageEventArgs args)
    {...}
}
```

When calling to operation.Execute(); not all the received events are being raised on the SyncOperation class.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Quite a bit of coce and I'm still not sure we have an overview... Maybe post TryFireMessageEvent too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared your code with a known-good example and I have my doubts about `private readonly string OnReceivedEventName` as object-key. You rely on string interning here, the 'normal' is a static object.

And this makes me wonder whether the normal generated events are thread-safe. Couldn't find a reference so quickly, but as a diagnostic:

```
public event MessageEventHandler OnReceived;
```

You *might* have a race condition then, but that would be very rare (and easy to minimize/eliminate). Do all the handlers get called?

Comment: I do not think that all the handlers get called. sometime the SyncOperation handler is called and sometime the MyProvider handler get called

Comment: @Anibas: I meant with the `;` in place.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain in more details what was the problem?

Comment: Then it was somewhere in the add/remove and related code. My guess is the use of string as object key, but that would only be dubious with multiple assemblies.